# sql Left join with linq lampda expression

Tags: .net, linq

I have a problem in making a left/right join with linq.

I have lets say

```
public class Customer
{
  prop string CustomerId { get; set; }
  prop string LanguageGuid { get; set; }
}

public class ReadOnlyCustomer
{
  prop string CustomerId { get; set; }
  prop string LanguageGuid { get; set; }
}
```

I have a lot of customers in the ReadonlyCustomer table.
In my case I dont have all the customers in customer table.
So I cant use the Join, i dont what the inner join.
I need the left or right join.

```
var test = db.Customer.Join(db.ReadOnlyCustomer, p => p.CustomerId, o => o.CustomerId, (c, o) => new ReadOnlyCustomer() { CustomerId = c.CustomerId, LanguageGuid = o.LanguageGuid ?? c.LanguageGuid });
```

At this point, I get a null pointer, because the query cant join on a null ref.

How can I do a left join equal to sql left join, where I get NULL for value that does not exist in the datasource.

This needs to be in lampda not comprehensing syntax like (from o in ....)

// dennis

Comment: Why the requirement that it can't be in 'comprehensing' syntax?  The only easy solution I know of only works with 'comprehensing' syntax: http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/left-join-right-join-using-linq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `GroupJoin`, sometimes in conjunction with a call to `DefaultIfEmpty()` afterwards to give a single null value for the group. You can then use `SelectMany()` to end up with one result per pair, noting that one of the values in the result may be null.

For example:

```
// Note: can only do a *left* join, so "bigger" table comes first
var test = db.ReadOnlyCustomer
             .GroupJoin(db.Customer,
                        p => p.CustomerId,
                        o => o.CustomerId,
                        (p, os) => new { p, os = os.DefaultIfEmpty() })
             // Each pair may have multiple os here
            .SelectMany(pair => pair.os.Select(o => new { pair.p, o }))
            // Flattened, but o may be null
            .Select(pair => new ReadOnlyCustomer {
                      CustomerId = pair.p.CustomerId,
                      LanguageGuid = o != null ? o.LanguageGuid ?? p.LanguageGuid
                                               : p.LanguageGuid
                    });
```

(Out of interest, *why* does this need to be in lambda syntax rather than as a query expression? Typically joins of all kinds are simpler to express in query expressions.)

Comment: Thx, this work nicely.. to answer your question of interest: I need to add more expression dynamicly to the query right before it fires. I only want to use the one of the way to do it, otherwise it will not look as nice. And I did want to learn how to do it in this form for query. I was not successful in finding a solution on google, we are not on best of term :P